# Element not found error while selecting dropdown in Java selenium

Tags: java, firefox, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

Here is the code i have written
I get the below error when the weblist selects second user from drop down the Error is
Caused by Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

The code is

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class SimpleBrowseroperation 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();        
    //driver.navigate().to("https://google.co.in");
    driver.navigate().to("https://testnwadmin.aditi.com/nwadmin/spages/home.aspx");
    List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='divLoginSection']/div/div[3]"));
    driver.findElement(By.id("Login1_txtEmailID")).sendKeys("testdata5@aditi.com");
    //driver.findElement(By.id("Login1_txtPassword")).sendKeys("Testing1*");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Login1_btnLogin")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sliding-navigation']/li[2]/a")).click();
    String ViewMorelink="//*[@id='divContentHolder']/div[2]/table[%s]/tbody/tr[3]/td";
    String ClkViewMore="//*[@id='divContentHolder']/div[2]/table[%s]/tbody/tr[3]//a[contains(text(),'View')]";
    String Covered="//*[@id='divContentHolder']/div[2]/table[%s]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[%s]/td[2]";
    String ViewDetails="//*[@id='divContentHolder']/div[2]/table[%s]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[%s]/td[3]/a";
    String TableRowCount="//*[@id='divContentHolder']/div[2]/table[%s]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr";
    String ViewCarrier="//*[@id='divContentHolder']/div[2]/table[%s]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[%s]/td[3]";
    String ClaimPayer="//*[@id='divContentHolder']/div[2]/table[%s]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[%s]/td[4]";

    Select WebList=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ddlSelectUser']")));
    List<WebElement> userlist = WebList.getOptions();
    int usercnt=userlist.size();
    System.out.println(usercnt);
    String[] linkTexts = new String[usercnt];
    int i = 0;
    for (WebElement e : userlist) 
    {
    linkTexts[i] = e.getText();
    i++;
    }
    for(int usrcnt=0;usrcnt<=usercnt;usrcnt++)
    {

        WebList.selectByIndex(usrcnt);
        > /
                    > somecode
                    > /

    }

}
}
```

Comment: As far as I know selectByIndex you need to use an integer but in the code usrcnt seems to be a sting. Probaly that might be the issue. Probably you can use selectByVisibleText

Comment: hey vinay moving the select inside the for loop fixed the issue                  for(int usrcnt=0;usrcnt<usercnt;usrcnt++)
  {
   Select WebList=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ddlSelectUser']")));

Comment: Guess inside the loop you are using i instead of the text. But logically selectByIndex will take integer and not sting values as arguments.

Comment: before for loop i am counting the number of items in the dropdown no where ia m using the string values for selectByIndex                         Select WebList1=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ddlSelectUser']")));
  List<WebElement> userlist = WebList1.getOptions();
  int usercnt=userlist.size();
  for(int usrcnt=0;usrcnt<usercnt;usrcnt++)
  {
   Select WebList=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ddlSelectUser']")));
   WebList.selectByIndex(usrcnt);

Comment: Hi Patil - when you've got extra information, it's best to edit your question to include it there. It's much more readable than if you post it as a response.

Comment: Hi Vince i was not asking an extra question i just posted the code which resolved my query that's all...